# What's the purpose of source vs. source-code tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Asking a question, I just noticed there are two seemingly identical tags (which aren't aliases at the time of this writing): [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) and [source-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-code).

I have no strong opinion about which one should be the "leading" tag here, but I think it'd make sense to merge them.

I also see that [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) has [source-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-code) suggested as a synonym, but lack the reputation to vote myself. So please consider that a nudge, everyone *with* high enough reputation.

Comment: I was going to say that [tag:source] obviously relates to sourcing of dot-scripts using `source` (in shells that support it) or the `.` (dot) utility, but the tag text is in conflict with that.

Comment: @Kusalananda it certainly is in conflict with that. Also, I am not sure every built-in of a shell deserves its own tag. Anyway, the questions on [tag:source] appear to be ... mixed (some synonymous with your interpretation, some with [tag:source-code]).

Comment: Perhaps [tag:source] should be split to a new [tag:source-command] and [tag:source-code]

Comment: This is a good question. I had created source-command to distinguish those questions. Looking at existing tags, we have several that are bash builtins. There's also the shell-builtin tag. Do we want *all* shell builtins to roll up to their corresponding shell tag (zsh/bash/etc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to have a tag for the shell builtin `source` specifically. It's not that special a feature that it wouldn't just fit under [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script) (or [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash), which is what most of those are tagged with anyway). Besides, `source` isn't even a standard command. [For POSIX-compatibility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot), it should be [dot-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dot-command) instead. Though [source-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-command) already exists, it's only been used by Jeff.

It would probably be best to make [source-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-code) the main tag and [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) an alias to make it more clear what it's about.

Or just remove [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) altogether if both [source-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-code) and [source-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-command) exist (are kept)?

Comment: I'm in favor of making [tag:source-code] the main tag with an alias of [tag:source]. On reflection, I don't see a big need for tags for shell built-ins, such as soure-command (or dot-command). I'd rather tag them with [tag:shell] or the shell in use.